# RELY Constraint in View

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-view

While learning inline_constraint and out_of_line_constraint for view. I get this example in oracle documentation.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm#i2126714

```
CREATE VIEW emp_sal (emp_id, last_name, 
      email UNIQUE RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE,
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id) RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE)
   AS SELECT employee_id, last_name, email FROM employees;
```

I have so many doubts in this statement:
**1) what is rely constaint** - This constraint is useful when queries typically access views instead of base tables, and the DBA thus needs to define the data relationships between views rather than tables. 

But in this example it is not materialized views so data will be accessed through base table only. Could you please explain function and when to use rely constraint. 
2) what is the use of unique key if we have disabled it like in this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) what is rely constraint

> View constraints, because they are unenforced, are usually specified with the RELY parameter to make them more useful.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002565

> Specify RELY to activate an existing constraint in NOVALIDATE mode for query rewrite in an unenforced query rewrite integrity mode.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002915

This means if a materialized view is created based on the view, it may rely on the constraint in allowing certain queries to be rewritten to use the materialized view instead of querying your base tables.

2) what is the use of unique key if we have disabled it like in this statement

All unique constraints on a view must be disabled. Basically these can be useful in order to allow query rewrite.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.
 I still have doubts, I am reading about this.